# shibd fails to start on upgraded 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

After an in-place upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 I'm unable to get `shibd` to start. The error is:

```
shibd[16228]: /usr/sbin/shibd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsaml.so.9: undefined symbol:  
 _ZN10xmltooling29AbstractXMLObjectUnmarshaller10unmarshallEPN11xercesc_3_110DOMElementEb
```

I've tried upgrading `opensaml2-tools` and `libsaml9:amd64`.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This kind of question keeps coming up, and soon we'll have a good reference Q&A to explain that 18.04 LTS will not be ready to perform this kind of upgrade until the first point release 18.04.1 - Good thing you made a backup of your drive before attempting this, eh?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is good that it's a VM and I have a pre-upgrade snapshot. Will your Q&A address whether it's worth spending time to install 18.04LTS from scratch vs. waiting for it to be ready for actual use?